# Pandas - Merge duplicate rows and create new columns for each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a pandas dataframe that includes several duplicate rows like below

```
|ID|Gender|Result|Date|
|1|M|Pos|1|
|1|M|Pos|10|
|2|F|Neg|5|
|2|F|Pos|7|
```

I want to merge the duplicate rows based on 'ID' column and the for each 'result' and 'Date' a new column were created, as like below

```
|ID|Gender|Result1|Date1|Result2|Date2|
|1|M|Pos|1|Pos|10|
|2|F|Neg|5|Pos|7|
```

what is the best way to tackle this issue? I think I should use `groupby()` but I do not have any idea about adding columns.

Comment: Any of the options from the duplicate will work. Just update your index columns to be `['ID', 'Gender']`

Comment: What kind of tool shows you pipe `|` seperated data for export? I see it alot and its rather difficult to recreate in my IDE. Is there an easy way to do that, like pd.read_clipboard() but for pipe seperated data?

Comment: `pd.read_clipboard(sep='|')` or `df.to_clipboard(sep='|')` @Andreas?

Comment: @HenryEcker wow, I wasn't aware read_clipboard has such a parameter .... that actually helps me a lot! Now I feel bad that I didn't just checked the docu and that I can't give you an accepted answer reward for that. Ah, have an Idea ;)